# Why is my summary in R only including some of my variables?

Tags: r, missing-data, p-value

I am trying to see if there is a relationship between number of bat calls and the time of pup rearing season. The pup variable has three categories: "Pre", "Middle", and "Post". When I ask for the summary, it only included the p-values for Pre and Post pup production. I created a sample data set below. With the sample data set, I just get an error.... with my actual data set I get the output I described above.

SAMPLE DATA SET:

```
 Calls<- c("55","60","180","160","110","50") 
 Pup<-c("Pre","Middle","Post","Post","Middle","Pre")
 q<-data.frame(Calls, Pup)
 q
 q1<-lm(Calls~Pup, data=q)
 summary(q1)
```

OUTPUT AND ERROR MESSAGE FROM SAMPLE:

```
> Calls    Pup
1    55    Pre
2    60 Middle
3   180   Post
4   160   Post
5   110 Middle
6    50    Pre

Error in as.character.factor(x) : malformed factor
In addition: Warning message:
In Ops.factor(r, 2) : ‘^’ not meaningful for factors
```

ACTUAL INPUT FOR MY ANALYSIS:

```
> pupint <- lm(Calls ~ Pup, data = park2)
summary(pupint)
```

THIS IS THE OUTPUT I GET FROM MY ACTUAL DATA SET:

```
Residuals:
Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-66.40 -37.63 -26.02  -5.39 299.93 

Coefficients:
        Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
 (Intercept)    66.54      35.82   1.858   0.0734 .
PupPost       -51.98      48.50  -1.072   0.2927  
PupPre        -26.47      39.86  -0.664   0.5118  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 80.1 on 29 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.03822,   Adjusted R-squared:  -0.02811 
F-statistic: 0.5762 on 2 and 29 DF,  p-value: 0.5683
```

Overall, just wondering why the above output isn't showing "Middle". Sorry my sample data set didn't work out the same but maybe that error message will help better understand the problem.

Comment: For many types of regression, you'll code categorical variables as dummies and end up with 1 fewer variables than the number of categories. In your case, Middle is the baseline http://sthda.com/english/articles/40-regression-analysis/163-regression-with-categorical-variables-dummy-coding-essentials-in-r/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For R to correctly understand a dummy variable, you have to indicate `Pup` is a cualitative (dummy) variable by using `factor`

```
> Pup <- factor(Pup)
> q<-data.frame(Calls, Pup)
> q1<-lm(Calls~Pup, data=q)
> summary(q1)

Call:
lm(formula = Calls ~ Pup, data = q)

Residuals:
    1     2     3     4     5     6 
  2.5 -25.0  10.0 -10.0  25.0  -2.5 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)    85.00      15.61   5.444   0.0122 *
PupPost        85.00      22.08   3.850   0.0309 *
PupPre        -32.50      22.08  -1.472   0.2374  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 22.08 on 3 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9097,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8494 
F-statistic:  15.1 on 2 and 3 DF,  p-value: 0.02716
```

If you want R to show all categories inside the dummy variable, then you must remove the intercept from the regression, otherwise, you will be in [variable dummy trap](https://www.statology.org/dummy-variable-trap/).

```
summary(lm(Calls~Pup-1, data=q))

Call:
lm(formula = Calls ~ Pup - 1, data = q)

Residuals:
    1     2     3     4     5     6 
  2.5 -25.0  10.0 -10.0  25.0  -2.5 

Coefficients:
          Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
PupMiddle    85.00      15.61   5.444  0.01217 * 
PupPost     170.00      15.61  10.889  0.00166 **
PupPre       52.50      15.61   3.363  0.04365 * 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 22.08 on 3 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9815,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9631 
F-statistic: 53.17 on 3 and 3 DF,  p-value: 0.004234
```

Answer (score 0):

If you include a categorical variable like `pup` in a regression, then it is including a dummy variable for each value within that variable except for one by default. You could show a coefficient for `pupmiddle` if you omit instead the intercept coefficient like this:

```
q1<-lm(Calls~Pup - 1, data=q)
```

Comment: That worked!! Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome.